# How does this code work ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm reading Adam's book Pro ASP .NET MVC 4 and I have a question what does this code do?

```
@Html.RouteLink(link, new
    {
        controller = "Product",
        action = "List",
        category = link,
        page = 1
    },
    new {
        @class = link == ViewBag.SelectedCategory ? "selected" : null
    })
```

Additionally, I have a controller with the method inside

```
public PartialViewResult Menu(string category = null)
{
            ViewBag.SelectedCategory = category;
            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
              .Select(x => x.Category)
              .Distinct()
              .OrderBy(x => x);
            return PartialView(categories);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You got to do some research about PartialViews and Routelink in google/bing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460117%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> RouteLink returns an anchor element (a element) that contains the
>   virtual path of the specified action.

It means it will generate following html a tag

```
<a href="myserver/Product/List...">linkstring</a>
```